# Can home assistant devices (like Amazon echo or Google home) return data without user invocation?

Tags: backend, actions-on-google, alexa-skills-kit, voice

I was thinking on some functionalities for a business action/skill for assistant speakers, but I have a question:

Is it possible to make the speakers return some data without user explicit invocation?

For example, I am saving some reminders in a backend and I want the speaker to remind me about them always 1 hour before, without the need of having to invoke the app on the speaker.

Is it currently supported? Could I configure from that backend the time before I want to get that reminder?

Thanks you all!

Answer (score 1):

The feature on the Assistant is known as a [push notification](https://developers.google.com/assistant/engagement/notifications). With the user's explicit permission, you will get a token that you can use to call an API at a later time of your choosing. The notification will be sent to the user, and they can accept the notification which will start a conversational flow with your Action.

The downside, however, is that currently notifications are only sent to mobile devices. They aren't sent to smart speakers.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are a bit out of date and I think the wording to your question title was a little confusing.  Rather than returning data to an API, you seemed to want to know if the device will speak data to a user based on inputs from an API.

At present, you can create reminders via an API, and Alexa will announce the reminder with a small amount of content that can be spoken to the user.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/alexa-reminders-api-reference.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Amazon doesn't support that capability yet.  As a builder of personal and home automation skills, I have accomplished that type of work flow by creating a virtual device that I can trigger and is recognized by Alexa.  Then, within the Alexa application, tie the device state change to a routine.

The approach doesn't allow me to provide dynamic content, yet.  But, I can tie different devices to canned messages that can then be sent to devices.